# Making IPhone View Re-Usable

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I have an IPhone application having a single view which has some text, an image and a video to be played there on screen. Now my goal is to make this view re-usable so others could use it in their apps.

Also the view should be first to be load on the application. Lets say if you have an app having 3 views and you want my re-usable View to be used in your app (now you have 4 views 3 + 1). How would you add it the simplest possible way so my view becomes the first view of your application and your current first view becomes the next one.

I need a guide for it. Is there any simplest readable guide available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To navigate between different view you'd use a UINavigationController. Another developer wanting to use your view as the first page, would simply set it as the root controller of the UINavigationController.

There is not something you can do to make sure that anyone who else who uses it, must use it as the first screen.

Comment: I need to write a guide for them :) Even I don't know how to use UINavigationController but now I will google for it.